# HTML not display in Console using Webclient

Tags: c#, webclient

I have the following snippet which I am trying to output the html of a particular website to console.

```
using System;
using System.Net;

namespace googleHTML
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            WebClient client = new WebClient();

            string htmlCode = client.DownloadString("http://www.google.com");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run it in console, nothing happens?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Console.Write(htmlCode);
```

`Console.ReadLine` reads a line of text **input** from the console stream.

Answer (score 1):

You don't do anything with the html, you're just storing it.

Try

```
Console.WriteLine(htmlCode);
```

after

```
string htmlCode = client.DownloadString..
```